# Symfony 4: bind vs arguments keyword to explicitly inject dependency

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, symfony4

As far as I am concerned there are two ways (both working properly for me) to explicitly inject a dependency to a service:

a) using the bind keyword

```
App\Service\ServiceA:
    bind:
        $myService: '@myserviceid'
```

b) using the arguments keyword

```
App\Service\ServiceA:
    arguments:
        $myService: '@myserviceid'
```

Is there any difference between them? Thank you!

Comment: Functionality, the two approaches are equivalent and will result in the same generated container.  bind is more typically used in the defaults section.  It's useful when you have multiple services with the same argument name expecting the same value.  Not so nice if you happen to use the same argument name for different values.  Don't know for sure why you attracted a drive by downvote there are many many people whose job is to downvote and you really can't expect them to waste their time explaining why.  Would not be kind.

Answer (score 1):

Bind is used in defaults configurations for services, for exemple to define scalar arguments for all services. It can be like the autowire, but the difference is that this last one can't autowire scalar arguments (e.g. strings and numbers). It's new in SYmfony 3.4.

You can check the doc here: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding